# Text with images in css columns

Tags: css

[image]

This is for my ebook app. Height of the columns will vary. So image location is difficult to predict. I use **-webkit-column-break-before: always;** to preserve images from being divided between columns. But this method leaves empty space.

Is it possible to fill empty space in the second column with text from the last? What do you think?

https://jsfiddle.net/rg9kvnys/

```
#mydiv{
  width:1000px;
  height:200px;
  -webkit-column-width:200px;
  border-style:solid;
 }

#image{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:red;
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: nop, text won't flow around image to fill a gap; :(

Comment: . . . after all it would around floatting elements : https://jsfiddle.net/rg9kvnys/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i might have commented too fast. you need to `float`  `#image` :

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  /* eventually */
  -moz-column-fill: balance;
  -webkit-column-fill: balance;
  column-fill: balance;
}

#image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
  -moz-column-break-before: always;
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
  column-break-before: always;
}
```

```html
<div ID="mydiv">
  But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
  human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely
  <div ID="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/190/190/people" /></div> painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some
  great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences,
  or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings
  of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are
  extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which
  of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant
  pleasure?
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rg9kvnys/3/

or without an `height` set and `column-fill` also that can come handy https://jsfiddle.net/rg9kvnys/2/